# Re installing webmin theme through command prompt

Tags: themes, webmin

I was changing my webmin theme and I don't really know what went wrong the theme doesnt seem to be loading correctly. How can I reset webmin back to the default the via putty command line

I know that if I want to change the theme I do this

```
nano /etc/webmin/config
```

then scroll down to where their is theme and then change theme name. But problem is I dont know what the default theme is called

my current broken theme is

```
theme=mscstyle3
```

I will aprreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

- Edit `/etc/webmin/config` and add the line

  ```
  theme=mscstyle3
  ```
- Edit `/etc/webmin/miniserv.conf` and add the line

  ```
  preroot=mscstyle3
  ```
- Restart Webmin with the command

  ```
  /etc/webmin/stop ; /etc/webmin/start
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your installation the default theme name might be **mscstyle3** or **mscstyle** but you should make sure it's in webmin folder.

Determine where your webmin installation is. Mine for example was at /usr/libexec/webmin.
Do an `ls -lh` there and look for folders ending with -theme. This will tell you the themes you have installed (also look for folders having the file VERSION inside, most likely this will be a theme)